# Java Reactor Pattern with java.io Package

Tags: java, io, nio, reactor

I see in several application source like Minecraft and JIrcs they both use java.io to implement Reactor Plugin (if I'm not wrong) and also in this [article](http://hillside.net/plop/plop99/proceedings/Fernandez3/RACPattern.PDF). So, what is the difference between java.io and java.nio when implementing Reactor Pattern? I mean, like performance advantage, process efficiency etc and where i can get good tutorial if you think java.io is the good solution to implement Reactor Pattern (since google give me tons of java.nio tuts not java.io as i want)

Comment: I'm not a fan of the Reactor pattern in any case but it certainly doesn't fit `java.io.`

Comment: @EJP Why is that so? Is it due to some limitations of Reactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you can get a conclusion with the below [information taken from the book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=saF6F-sO_H0C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=Java%20Reactor%20Pattern%20with%20java.io%20Package&source=bl&ots=Ublt9zU3UE&sig=RZLjy2Sd8serfqHp9VUrgeJ1-Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VbUDUbGtNs2HrAeAhYHgAw&ved=0CHkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Java%20Reactor%20Pattern%20with%20java.io%20Package&f=false) 
at page no.42

> java.io.* classes use the **decorator design pattern**. The decorator
>   design pattern attaches responsibilities to objects at runtime.
>   Decorators are more flexible than inheritance because the
>   **inheritance attaches responsibility to classes at compile time**. The java.io.* classes use the decorator pattern to construct different
>   combinations of behaviour at runtime based on some basic classes.

and 43.

> Java has no long been suited for developing programs that perform a
>   lot of I/O operations. Furthermore, commonly needed tasks such as file
>   locking, non-blocking and asynchronous I/O operations and ability to
>   map file to memory were not available. Non-blocking I/O operations
>   were achieved through work around such as multithreading or using JNI.
>   The **New I/O API** (aka **NIO**) in J2SE 1/4 has changed this
>   situation.
>          A server's availability to handle several client requests effectively depends on how it uses I/O streams. When a server has to
>   handle hundreds of clients simultaneously, it must be able to use I/O
>   services concurrenty, one way to cater for this scenario in Java is to
>   use threads but having almost one-to-one ratio of threads (100 clients
>   will have 100 threads) is prone to anormous **thread overhead and can
>   result in performance and scalability problems due to consumtion of
>   memory stacks** (i.e. each thread has its stack, Refer **Q34**,
>   **Q42** in Java section) and **CPU context switching**(i.e. switching between threads as opposed to doing real computation.). To overcome
>   this problem, a new set of non-blocking I/O classes have been
>   introduced to the Java platform in java.nio package. The non-blocking
>   I/O mechanism is built around Selectors and channels. **Channels**,
>   **Buffers** and **Selectors** are the core of the NIO.

and [read more](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=saF6F-sO_H0C&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=Java%20Reactor%20Pattern%20with%20java.io%20Package&source=bl&ots=Ublt9zU3UE&sig=RZLjy2Sd8serfqHp9VUrgeJ1-Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VbUDUbGtNs2HrAeAhYHgAw&ved=0CHkQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=Java%20Reactor%20Pattern%20with%20java.io%20Package&f=false).
Here are some reference links which provide Java IO vs Java NIO : 
[Java IO Faster Than NIO – Old is New Again!](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/), [Java IO vs Java NIO](http://dukegenius.blogspot.in/2012/03/java-io-vs-java-nio.html) and [IO vs. NIO – Interruptions, Timeouts and Buffers](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/io-vs-nio-interruptions-timeouts-and.html).

Comment: "Java has no long been suited ..." Does it really say that?

Comment: @EJP `Java's I/O operations is more complicated than C/C++ to support internationalization (i18n). Java internally stores characters (char type) in 16-bit UCS-2 character set. But the external data source/sink could store characters in other character set, in fixed length of 8-bit or 16-bit, or in variable length of 1 to 4 bytes. As a consequence, Java needs to differentiate between byte-based I/O for processing raw bytes or binary data, and character-based I/O for processing texts made up of characters.` [read more...](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j5b_io.html)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really true that NIO is faster. **Paul Tyma** demolished that **myth** sometime back.

http://mailinator.blogspot.in/2008/02/kill-myth-please-nio-is-not-faster-than.html

http://paultyma.blogspot.in/2008/03/writing-java-multithreaded-servers.html

Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand the differences between blocking and non-blocking I/O. The `java.io` package does NOT support non-blocking I/O so it won't scale for a large number of connections. Moreover, with blocking I/O you can only resort to the terrible *one-client-to-one-thread model* which is completely unsuitable for low-latency systems. I suggest you take a look on [this article](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/04/the-simplicity-of-coralreactor/) written by me about an asynchronous network I/O library that implements the reactor pattern, so you can understand how non-blocking plays a key role in high-performance systems.

Comment: Disclaimer: you wrote the article?

Comment: Yes, I did. I edited my answer to state that. I will do that from now on. Thanks.